# AdminCreds parameter not found in JSON DSC

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to add an extension to an azure arm template, so when it loops around it adds the extension to each vm, but I'm getting an error where it doesn't recognise the credentials parameter.

The full JSON is at the link below:

https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/7uvwdZ6e

The error I'm getting is:

```
VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CreateADPDC'. Error message: "The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: A parameter cannot be found that 
matches parameter name 'AdminCreds'.
Another common error is to specify parameters of type PSCredential without an explicit type. Please be sure to use a typed parameter in DSC Configuration, for example:
    configuration Example {
        param([PSCredential] $UserAccount)
```

Any idea where I've gone wrong on this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error comes from your configuration\arm template interaction, if you have the AdminCreds credentials parameter there, i think you need to use protectedsettings to pass it:

```
"protectedSettings": {
    "configurationArguments": {
        "adminCreds": {
            "userName": "xxx",
            "password": "yyy"
        }
    }
}
```

configuration should look like this (so should contain adminCreds input parameter with that particular type):

```
Param (
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
    other_params
)
```

Comment: Hi, the configuration file has been uploaded to https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/VxjQZTuS   could you check it please. I'm not sure about the line `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ]($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)`

Comment: yeah, that line is fine, except it doesnt do anything, you need to save it to a variable. i usually do this: `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainNetbiosName}\$($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)`

Comment: does it matter that this server isn't domain joined?

Comment: i dont think so, it would just create credentials with those domain\username combination. you wont be able to do much unless you domain join, obviously. btw, not sure what you are after, [here's a link](http://4c74356b41.com/post5775) to sql always on deployment to Azure, it has AD deployment as well. also, azure arm templates example repo has working AD deployment

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to remove the admincreds and that means I can remove all the mandatory parameters, thanks for your help :)